# Codelite menu bar has been hidden

Tags: codelite

Hi I'm currently using CodeLite for my IDE, and I cannot seem to find a way to bring back my menu bar. Originally I was just trying to add other bars back by clicking through, but I ended up un-checking the menu bar, and now it's completely hidden.  [Hidden menu bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8hW1.png)

Answer (score 8):

The default keyboard for that is `Ctrl-F11` (minimal view)
This includes:

- Hide the menu bar
- Hide the toolbar
- Hide the docking windows captions

You can re-enable them all or separately:

- Hit `Ctrl-F11` again
- From the `Goto Anything` (`Ctrl-Shift-P`), type `menu bar` and select it
- From the menu bar (once it visible again) `Menu -> View -> Show Tool Bar`, `Menu -> View -> Show Menu Bar` etc

HTH,
Eran

Answer (score 1):

You can reset CodeLite by deleting the following folder. Be sure to run the Setup Wizard again after doing this

Close CodeLite

Delete the following directory:
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\codelite

Then restart CodeLite and rerun the Setup wizard. You will need to re-configure and re-make any templates you had saved, but you won't lose your work.

I know this is an extremely late answer haha, but I ran into the same issue a few days ago and just got it fixed. I hope anyone in the future who runs into the same issue sees this and save them the headache of waiting ages for help.