# Codelite page gone blank

Tags: c++, codelite

I have been writing code in codelite for c++ since past 20 days, today morning while writing code, by mistake i clicked somewhere and the top menu of options and side menu of projects vanished. I tried many things but i couldnt get them back. I am not a technical person and learning c++ from a tutorial. Now my codelite page is blank and i am stuck. I have unistalled and installed again but when i opened it, it still shows the blank page . I dont know what to do. Is there any history i need to delete from my laptop(for reinstallation) or need to do something in codelite , to get back default codelite page which comes when newly installed.Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Codelite menu bar has been hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828978/codelite-menu-bar-has-been-hidden)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828978/codelite-menu-bar-has-been-hidden

Answer (score 1):

might be a little late here but I think I had your problem, if someone encounters similar

1. Double check what "perspective" you are on
2. Ctrl + M key can minimize several open views such as the "workspace view" and the "debugger view"

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, this happened to me too. It happens just because you are on full screen mode, and because you are currently in the workspace folder in which your source code is. Just follow these:

- press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to you exit full screen mode. You should now be
  able to view the top menu.
- now go to `view` in the top menu and click on the Workspace pane.
- After the Workspace pane appears, you will notice that you are now
  in the workspace folder rather than on the source code file. Now, to go
  to the file, click on the workspace on which your file is, click on
  the project name under which your source code is, click on src,
  then click on the file, e.g. `main.cpp`

Post your doubts if you still have any

Answer (score 0):

I got an empty workspace panel after updating the packages in msys2. I used codelite version 15 from msys2. After removing it from msys2 (`pacman -R mingw-w64-x86_64-codelite`), and installing version 17 separately from msys2, the workspace panel appeared with some components, and there was a "hidden tabs" button in it, through which I returned the list of projects.

Probably the program codelite from msys2 was not static, and updating the dynamic libraries caused the problem. Probably it was WxWidgets DLLs. An occasion to think about the separation of development tools and the development environment for me.